# Cookie is not recognised in PHP

Tags: php, web, cookies

I get `Notice: Undefined index: i` during the first reload of page with cookies

```
if( (isset($_COOKIE["i"])) && !empty($_COOKIE["i"])   ){
    setcookie("i",$_COOKIE["i"]+1);
    }
else{
    setcookie("i",1);
}

echo $_COOKIE["i"]; //here is the error
```

but after 2nd reload,it's OK.

Comment: By first reload, do you actually mean the result of an F5?

Comment: whent I open the .php for the first time

Comment: Calling `setcookie` does not change the `$_COOKIE` array. That array is populated at the start of the request and then it is effectively read-only.

Comment: And how to avoid the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not use the `$_COOKIE` array, but a variable

```php
<?php

// Use a variable
$cookieValue = 1;

// Check the cookie
if ((isset($_COOKIE["i"])) && !empty($_COOKIE["i"])) {
    $cookieValue = (int)$_COOKIE["i"] + 1;
}

// Push the cookie
setcookie("i", $cookieValue);

// Use the variable
echo $cookieValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
    setcookie("i",1);
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. This also clears up the intent of the person answering as sometimes reviewers can look at a code only answer and totally miss what was intended.